# Underworld Connections: Tapping the Land for mana and ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say i enchant a land with [Underworld Connections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Underworld%20Connections). Would i be able to tap said land for mana, and use the ability of Underworld Connections concurrently?

Answer (score 9):

No.

Tapping a land doesn't actually produce mana, activating its ability does. Tapping is merely the paying of the cost to do so.

Unlike abilities that read "Whenever enchanted land is tapped"<sup>[1]</sup>, it's not actually tapping the land that causes Underworld Connections's effect. Tapping is merely paying part of the cost to do so.

As part of activating either the abilities, you will need to tap the land, which will leave you unable to activate the other ability.

Like in real life, just because two abilities have the same cost doesn't mean you can pay the price just once for both.

---

1. An example of such an ability is [Utopia Sprawl](http://magiccards.info/di/en/99.html)'s. Tapping the enchanted Forest for mana produces {G} as normal and triggers Utopia Sprawl's ability to produce a second mana.

Answer (score 2):

No, the following rule makes this pretty clear:

> 305.6. The basic land types are Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. If an object uses the words "basic land type," it’s referring to one of these subtypes. **A land with a basic land type has the intrinsic ability "(tap): Add [mana symbol] to your mana pool," even if the text box doesn't actually contain that text or the object has no text box.** For Plains, [mana symbol] is (W); for Islands, (U); for Swamps, (B); for Mountains, (R); and for Forests, (G). See rule 107.4a. Also see rule 605, "Mana Abilities."

So then, if you play Underworld Connections on a Swamp, you now have the following

> **Swamp**
>
> *Basic Land - Swamp*
>
> (Tap): Add (B) to your mana pool
>
> (Tap), Pay 1 life: Draw a card.

Tapping is part of the cost of each ability, so you can tap the land to pay either cost, but not both at the same time

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't pay two separate tap costs with a single tap, just as how in real life you can't pay for two separate $1 charges with the same dollar.  To be precise, you can't even activate the abilities at the same time; you have to activate one first and pay its cost, and then afterwards the fact that the land is tapped will prevent you from paying the cost for the other ability.

Comment: The canonical Magic analogy is that you can't use the same mana to pay for two different things. (Along with that, just remember that things before the colon in the ability are costs.)