# Do card abilities that grant mana stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, if I have a creature card that says

> Creatures you control have "{T}: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool."

and I have two of these creatures out, do they stack so I can tap a creature to get two mana?

Comment: i do not think this is a duplicate of either of those. Although the actual rule is that the cards end up with 2 separate tap abilities, it is not clear that the OP knows this. His question is not about a card with 2 separated tap abilities, but about having multiple cards that grant the same ability.

Comment: I read the title as asking about a creature with "[multiple] abilities that grant mana" and whether those abilities would all be activated by tapping the creature. This would make it a duplicate of the other questions, which similarly ask whether paying a single cost can activate multiple abilities that have that cost.

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate. We already have tons of questions about multiple tap abilities. Here's [one](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13520/6692). To address Gendolkari's comment, in that question, Underworld Connections grants the land an additional ability, which is exactly the same as this scenario. If it gets reopened, I will start another close vote.

Comment: How did @murgtroid99 manage to close the question alone with Community♦?

Comment: @Rainbolt [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) says that this is a new option that lets the asker close as a duplicate. You can see this by hovering over Community's name in the close reason banner.

Comment: In the game rules, it is the same as having 2 separate tap abilities. But the question is about cards that grant abilities, NOT about cards that have abilities. The other question doesn't at all address the idea of being granted the same ability multiple times. It is not clear at all that the OP already knows that being granted the same ability multiple times will result in the same thing as simply having 2 separate tap abilities.

Comment: In the game rules, it is *exactly* the same as having 2 different tap abilities. Once a card is a permanent on the battlefield, having an ability on the card is for all intents and purposes exactly the same as having said ability granted by a continuous effect. And, as I just pointed out, the closure by Community indicates that OP himself said that the linked question answered his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creature has two copies of the ability to tap for mana. However each one is separately activated, and you have to pay by tapping the creature for either of them. So you get a choice: Use the first copy of the ability to tap for one mana, or use the second. You can't use both.

So no, you only can get one mana per creature in this case.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I can cut a few of them from my deck then.